# Who are we, and where am I?

Tags: riddle

We twist and turn, going round and round.

No need to worry, we can take the strain.

While some of us are delicate and timely,

Others can lift more than the strongest man.

I myself prefer to peacefully take notes in a diary.

Who are we, and where am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a spring?

Specifically

> The coil which binds a diary together.

Most of the reasons for this I believe are self explanatory.

Delicate and timely:

> As in the time of year, Spring.

Comment: rot13(Lbh'er 90% gur jnl gurer. Pybfr rabhtu gung V'yy tvir vg gb lbh nf vgf frznagvpf bgurejvfr. Gur pbeerpg nafjref ner: pbvy bs n fcevat; fgenva vf n culfvpf grez yvaxrq gb rkgrafvba; fbzr fcevatf ner hfrq va jngpurf (gvzryl); bguref ner hfrq jvgu urnil znpuvarel; guvf bar vf hfrq va n cra.)

Comment: Ah very kind of you  I knew it was there abouts

Answer (score 2):

You are

> **cranes**.
>  You specifically are in **New Orleans**, I'm guessing?

We twist and turn, going round and round.
No need to worry, we can take the strain.

> One meaning of **crane** is a machine used to raise and lower heavy weights, at the end of a pivoting arm that rotates about a fixed vertical axis. Thus it twists and turns, and can take the strain of a heavy weight.

While some of us are delicate and timely,

> Another meaning of **crane** is a wading bird with a long, straight bill and long legs and neck.  They are, by comparison to their mechanical namesakes, quite delicate indeed.  (I don't know what "timely" references.)

Others can lift more than the strongest man.

> Yup.

I myself prefer to peacefully take notes in a diary.

> You in particular are, perhaps, yet another crane: Emma Rose Crane, of [The Crane Diaries](https://www.aprylbaker.com/the-ghost-files-copy) series of books. I know nothing of the books, but found that at least in book one, *Homecoming*, she has come home to the city of New Orleans.

Comment: Unfortunately not the right answer. Rot13(Vs guvf *jrer* gur fbyhgvba, V'q unir gnttrq vg jvgu jbeqcynl. Nyfb, gur gvzryl pbzcbarag vf whfg nf vzcbegnag nf gur erfg bs gur chmmyr.) Great attempt though! +1

Comment: @user3303504 Huh. I was pretty sure that would be it :) Oh well!